# Best way to process objects one by one in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-asynctask, task

I created a subclass of ArrayList:

```
public class ProcessQueue<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    private OnItemAdded mListener;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E object) {
        boolean result = super.add(object);

        if (mListener != null)
            mListener.onItemAdded(object);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E object) {
        super.add(index, object);

        if (mListener != null)
            mListener.onItemAdded(object);
    }


    public void setOnItemAddedListener(OnItemAdded listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnItemAdded {
        public void onItemAdded(Object object);
    }
}
```

Once an object is added:

```
@Override
public void onItemAdded(Object object) {
    new ProcessTask().execute((String) object);
}
```

I do the following to add an item into the processqueue list:

```
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    mProcessItem.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

So all my object are added withing the same task. Since the ProcessTask that i run for my objects is a very a bit big, is there any way to process the added items one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to run your calls ProcessTask.execute on a separate thread, one at a time, while not using up the UI thread? Not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but if that is what you mean, then you can use a Handler that is running on its own thread, and post a Runnable to the handler for each task.

Initialize the thread like this, but only do it once for your application. You don't want to create a new thread each time you start some activity.

```
HandlerThread ht = new HandlerThread("foo");
ht.start();
Handler processHandler = new Handler(ht.getLooper());
```

And then execute your tasks on the thread:

```
@Override
public void onItemAdded(final Object object) {
    processHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new ProcessTask().execute((String) object);
        }
    });
}
```